# Case Statement VS IF Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm getting different results using an `if` statement vs a `switch` statement.

This code recognizes if I say "hello" and if it does then it says "hello" back:

```
if (e.Result.Text == "Hello")
{
    JARVIS.Speak("Hello");
}
```

This `switch` statement should do the same thing:

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;

switch (speech)
{
    case "hello":
        JARVIS.Speak("Hello");
        break;
}
```

Why is it that in the `if` statement, I am allowed to say anything before/after "hello" *(e.g. "Well hello there")* and it will still recognize and reply back, whereas in the `case` statement if you say any words in front of / after "hello" it won't recognize and reply back?

Comment: let's see your entire switch statement.

Comment: String comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: use `"Hello".ToUpper();` and make your cases all upper case or all lower case with ToLower.

Comment: also, you could very likely solve this yourself just by printing out e.Result.Text

Comment: No it does not do the same thing. If it did there woulkd be no need for your question would there? Can only guess why without the full switch statement.

Comment: That is the full case statement: `switch (speech) { case "hello":
JARVIS.Speak("Hello");
break;`

Comment: @Grant Winney, Yup, I guess so: `string speech = e.Result.Text;`

Comment: Do it in this way, `string speech = e.Result.Text;` now use `speech` for both, `switch` and `if` statements

Comment: What do you mean by "I am allowed to say anything before/after "hello""

Comment: @Jay, E.g "Well hello" or "Hello there". See there is a word before hello in the first example and a word after hello in the second example.

Comment: Neither "Well hello" or "Hello there" are equal to "Hello" or "hello".  So, none of us understand your question.

Comment: I get that, but `if ("Well hello" == "hello")` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: Are you sure you've actually tried this? Somehow I think you were testing with `if (e.Result.Text.Contains("hello"))`, or something similar. The code you show *can not* exhibit the behavior that you describe.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement and the `case` statement behave differently because you have different values in them:

```
if (e.Result.Text == "Hello")
{
   JARVIS.Speak("Hello"); // This will be executed if e.Result.Text is "Hello"
}
```

Where-as the switch statement (code from your comments):

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;
switch (speech)
{
   case "hello":
      JARVIS.Speak("Hello"); // This will be executed if e.Result.Text is "hello"
      break;
}
```

In C#, "Hello" and "hello" are two different values.

One solution would be to call `.ToLower()` on `e.Result.Text`:

`string speech = e.Result.Text.ToLower()`;

Comment: Or the overload of `string.Equals()` that allows for case-insensitive comparison.